# Java procedures of extending abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, extend

I am not clear about the procedure of extending a class. Given the following piece of code, why the output is 32?

```java
class Rts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(zorg(new RtsC()));
    }

    static int zorg(RtsA x) {
        return x.f()*10 + x.a;
    }
}

abstract class RtsA {
    int a = 2;
    int f() { return a; }
}

class RtsB extends RtsA {
    int a = 3;
    int f() { return a; }
}

class RtsC extends RtsB {
    int a = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, fields aren't overridden, so all this is equivalent to

```
public class Rts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(zorg(new RtsC()));
    }
    static int zorg(RtsA x) {
        return x.f()*10 + x.a;
    } 
}

abstract class RtsA {
  int a = 2;
  int f() { return a; }
}
class RtsB extends RtsA {
  int b = 3;
  int f() { return b; }
}
class RtsC extends RtsB {
  int c = 4;
}
```

The implementation of `f()` for an object of type `RtsC` comes from `RtsB`, since that is the lowest-level class that overrides `f()`, so its implementation is used, and that returns `b`, which is `3`.  That's multiplied by `10`, and then added to the `a` from `RtsA`, since `zorg` only knows that `x` is of type `RtsA`, so that field is used.  That's `3 * 10 + 2 = 32`.

(Note that the fact that `RtsA` is abstract didn't come into this at all; that mostly only matters when you have abstract methods to worry about.)

Comment: I have another question about it. Since I invoke zorg(new RtsC()) in my main function, as you said, zorg only knows that x is of type RtsA, how we use this x to invoke f()? My understanding is the object of RtsC upcast to RtsA automatically. Confused

Comment: If you override a method in a subclass, its always the overriding method that gets called.

Comment: I mean you said 1：The implementation of f() for an object of type RtsC comes from RtsB. 2:since zorg only knows that x is of type RtsA. In the first sentence, the type of x is RtsC, why become RtsA in the second sentence. I think x.f() and x.a both should be RtsC

Comment: @Weiting, as far as Java is concerned, it's simple as this: methods can be overridden, variables cannot; variables can only be [hidden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). If you want the behaviour you describe, then you need to make an `int getA()` method in `RtsA` and override it in the subclasses.

Comment: As you have discovered, this behaviour is confusing. For this reason you should never hide variables. Make all of your fields `private`: then in addition to avoiding the confusion of variable hiding, you'll have [encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) classes.